# apktool unpack apk and then packed, Inflate Error <unknown> (file zip crc32:00000000)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apktool

unity 2018

apktool_2.4.0.jar

run unity packed apk:A log is:

```
E/Unity(3302): Unable to read header from archive file:
E/Unity(3302):
E/Unity(3302): 创建AssetBundle文件失败 AsserBundleCreateRequest prefab/effect/
E/Unity(3302):
E/Unity(3302): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
```

run myself packed apk/D log [infinite print log]:

```
E/Unity(3132): 
E/Unity(3132):  (Filename:  Line:212)
E/Unity(3132):  Inflate Error: <unknown> (file zip crc32 : 00000000) (result: fffffffb)
E/Unity(3132):
```

1. use unity pack an apk:A
2. use apktool unpack apk:A, get apk dir:B [apktool.bat d -r]
3. move out asset and lib from dir:B
4. pack dir:B as an apk:C without asset and lib [apktool.bat --force b]
5. add asset and lib to apk:C [aapt a]
6. sign my apk:C get a new apk/D
7. run my apk/D, get infinite log

Answer (score 0):

The problem results from the use of jarsigner. To solve the problem, just use apksigner to sign the APK.